# How to pass keyValuePair[] while calling c# dll in python?

Tags: c#, python

I have a C# method defined like below :

```
public void MyFunction(string name, KeyValuePair<string, object>[] values)
{......}
```

now I want to call this function in python (import clr). I've tried two ways to pass parameters.

```
MyFunction("mytest",[{'x1':10},{'x2':20}])
```

and

```
MyFunction("mytest",{'x1':10,'x2':20})
```

but i got same error for both ways:  No method matches given arguments for MyFunction.

I wonder a right way to pass parameters of `keyValuePair<>[]`